# How to use ShowMetroDialogAsync() using mahapps api

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have looked at the documentation at http://mahapps.com/controls/dialogs.html but I am still not sure how to use it. There is no documentation for ShowMetroDialogAsync().

Comment: await ShowMetroDialogAsync(MetroWindow, BaseMetroDialog) ? http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/DialogManager/M/ShowMetroDialogAsync

Comment: I tried that but I am not able to create the instance of BaseMetroDialog. have you tired it ?

Comment: BaseMetroDialog is an abstract class. You have to implement your own class. I have not tried...

Comment: did you find the answer to this? because i m also stuck on this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create the dialog as a control like this:

```
<metro:BaseMetroDialog x:Class="Example.Dialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:metro="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    Title="My new dialog">
  <TextBlock Text="Example" />
</metro:BaseMetroDialog>
```

Then, from another MetroWindow, you can show the dialog with something like this:

```
var dialog = new Example.Dialog()
await this.ShowMetroDialogAsync(dialog);
```

Comment: How to close it from inside the dialog?

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code:

```
await DialogManager.ShowMessageAsync(this, "Message Title here", "Your message description here");
```

The this keyword references your window

Comment: The OP asked for `ShowMetroDialogAsync` not `ShowMessageAsync`.  The former allows for custom content